# Why is a permutation of a set called a sequence?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, definition

I am trying to understand the formal definitions of a permutation. This one is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation):

> In mathematics, the notion of permutation relates to the act of
>   arranging all the members of a set into some sequence or order

A sequence is an enumeration of objects with repetitions allowed. When I am permuting a set (this already implies that all objects in it are unique), none of its permutations can have repeated elements. So why is it defined as a sequence?

One of the other definitions is that *a permutation is a sequence that contains all elements of the set exactly once*.

Why is there again an emphasis on calling it a sequence?

**Why not just call a permutation a set?**

Also, permutations can be made from a subset of the original set, ie. I can take 3 elements from a set at a time that contains 5 elements and then permute them. So, the resultant permutations will not contain all the elements of the set exactly once. So how does the second definition hold up there?

Please note that I do not have a pure mathematics background, so explanations in "laymans terms" would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A set has no order; $\{ 1,2,3 \}$ and $\{ 1,3,2 \}$ are **the same** set. Thus, how to distinguish two permutations ?

Comment: A set with an "order", like a listing, is a *sequence*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes but not all permutations of a set will have an order to them, they just might be a random arrangement. That's whats getting to me, there is no guarantee a permutation of a set will display an order, yet it is called a sequence(which implies some order).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Regarding your first comment - yes now I understand why it is not called a set. But then why call it a sequence, if there is no order guaranteed? Please don't tell me a random arrangement is also some sort of ordering. Is it ?

Comment: In set language a *sequence* $(a_0, a_1, \ldots a_n)$ is a function from $\{ 0, 1, \ldots n \}$ to $A$ such that $a_i \in A$. This is the way to "order" the elements of the sequence: Of course, repetitions are allowed.

Comment: Thus, starting from $(a,b,c)$ we consider the function $f$ such that $f(1)=a, f(2)=b$ and $f(3)=c$. Then the permutation $(a,c,b)$ will be defined by $g$ such that $g(1)=a, g(2)=c$ and $g(3)=b$.

Comment: With "order" I do not mean $<$ or similar; I mean only that we have to distinguish a first element, a second one, and so one. If we have not put the elements in "places", we cannot change their "places".

Comment: @ng.newbie: It seems to me that you misinterpret "order" as "something that appears ordered to humans". Actually "order" here just means “for any two values $a$ and $b$, we can tell which one comes before the other.”

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So when you say a sequence is a function from a set. Do you mean that the sequence is the range of the function? I am getting really confused. Also when you say that this a way to "order" the elements, then do you mean that the order is the function. Also, I don't know what you mean by - If we hav not put the elemnts is "places", we cannot change their "places"

Comment: A sequence is a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition) and a function is a *set*.

Comment: @MauroALLERGRANZA So a sequence is both a function and a set?? I dont think thats correct. A function is just a mapping rule from one set to another. AFAIK.

Comment: All functions can be expressed as sets. A function $f:D\to R$ is a set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ from $D\times R$ where for each $x\in D$, there is exactly one pair in $f$ such that the first element is $x$. Then for each $x\in D$, we say $f(x)=y$ where $(x,y)$ is that unique pair that starts with $x$. This is an equivalent description of a function.

Comment: A sequence is a function, not the range of the function. Consider Mauro's example above. The range of $f$ is $\{a,b,c\}$, a set. There is no order here, so it is not a sequence. Our function $f$, however, tells us our sequence. The first element is $f(1)$, the second element is $f(2)$, the $n$-th element is $f(n)$. Where the range only tells us what elements our sequence uses, the function tells us the order in which we use these elements, i.e. the whole sequence.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What about permutations that don't contain all elements of the original set in the permutation. For example $\{a,b,c\}$ we can now have permutations of selecting 2 objects from the original set of 3 - that subset of 2 objects is not a sequence of the original set - its a subset AFAIK. So my point is that how can you call all permutations of a set as sequences ?